# Why does Milnor need to move to the Riemann sphere to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, differential-topology

On pages 8 and 9 of [Topology from the differentiable viewpoint](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnortop.pdf), Milnor proves the fundamental theorem of algebra. He does so by first turning our polynomial $P:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ into a function $f:\hat{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ on the Riemann sphere. But, I don't see why moving to $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is necessary. Here's the argument:

> Next observe that $f$ has only a finite number of critical points; for $P$
>   fails to be a local diffeomorphism only at the zeros of the derivative
>   polynomial $P$ and there are only finitely many
>   zeros since $P'$ is not identically zero. The set of regular values of $f$, being a sphere with finitely many points removed, is therefore connected. Hence the locally constant function $\#f^{-1}(y)$ must actually be constant
>   on this set. Since $\#f^{-1}(y)$ can't be zero everywhere, we conclude that
>   it is zero nowhere. Thus $f$ is an onto mapping, and the polynomial $P$
>   must have a zero.

I don't see why we can't just apply this argument to $P$ directly. After all, a plane with finitely many points removed is still connected; this property isn't unique to the sphere.

> **Question.** If we try to replace $f$ with $P$ in Milnor's proof, what goes wrong?

Comment: The point is that the plane is not compact, while the Riemann sphere is. If you look a bit upper on page 8, you read that when $M$ is compact, $f^{-1}(x)$ consists of finetely many points for any regular value (this is why he states that the set of regular points is connected). If $M$ is not compact this can fail.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\exp \colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$. This has only finitely many critical points (none, to be exact), hence the set of regular values is connected (it's $\mathbb{C}$). Yet $\exp$ is not surjective. The cardinality-of-preimage function isn't locally constant in that case. To have the local constantness of $\# f^{-1}(y)$, you need the closedness of $f(M)$, and for that, compactness of the domain is useful.

Comment: Okay. It makes sense that there should be a reason why this argument fails for $\exp$. But honestly, I don't get how closedness of $f(M)$ helps us here. Can I ask you to state explicitly the theorem that Milnor is making implicit use of in which closedness features?

Comment: If $f(M)$ isn't closed, pick $y \in \overline{f(M)}\setminus f(M)$. It's a regular value, $\# f^{-1}(y) = 0$, but every neighbourhood of $y$ contains points with $\# f^{-1}(z) > 0$. Closedness of the image isn't sufficient, but it's one necessary condition. What Milnor uses is that $y \mapsto \# f^{-1}(y)$ is locally constant on the set of regular values, and as we saw, if the set of regular values is dense (which by Sard's theorem is quite common for functions considered in differential topology), closedness of the image is necessary for that.

Comment: We need more. In the situation here, essentially one needs to see that $P$ induces an unbranched unlimited covering [what in topology is just a covering] of the set of regular values. One can have local-constantness without the map inducing an unbranched unlimited covering, but I think when the domain is a compact manifold without boundary, and the target is a manifold of the same dimension it's an if-and-only-if.